# The $Locale global value provider returns wrong datetimeFormat value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime, locale, format

I noticed that lightning have some problem with datetime format. Seems like issue with `$Locale.dateTimeFormat` that returns wrong value. I set-up my Salesforce org User locale settings to English(United States) so I expecting datetime value formatted according to [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5): `2/07/2018 8:00 AM` but I recieved datetime in following format: `Jul 2, 2018 8:00:00 AM`. Additionally line: `console.log($Locale.dateTimeFormat);` shows following format: `MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a`.

This is known and reported Issue or I need additional configuration for correct datetime formats on Lightning JS side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_locale_value_provider.htm) is pretty clear (imo) on this one,

> The framework’s number and date formatting are based on Java’s
>   DecimalFormat and DateFormat classes.

and the format sample in it:

> "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a"

so:

> Jul 2, 2018 8:00:00 AM

seems accurate. That being said, you will have to do the formatting client side.
Fortunately, the same documetnation, provides a link towards [client-side localization support on input and output components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_l10n.htm) and recommends using [lightning:formattedDateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedDateTime.htm)

Sample component markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="datetime" type="DateTime"/>
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.datetime}" timeZone="Europe/Berlin" 
                             year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" hour="2-digit"
                             minute="2-digit" second="2-digit"/>
```

The doc [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5) you are referring to is for platform specific supported locales, vs Lightning's [$Locale Global Value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_locale_value_provider.htm), which is used to retrieve certain user prefered locales, which in turn can be used to help with the Number and Date Formatting Client side.

Comment: Thanks @glls . You have right but I wonder why `$Locale.dateTimeFormat` is different from format described in [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5). IMHO this is very misleading.

Comment: I believe that doc you are referring to is for platform specific supported locales, vs Lightning's $Locale Global Value, which is used to retrieve certain user prefered locales, which in turn can be used to help with the Number and Date Formatting Client side, but i understand your confusion.

Comment: I want to get same datetime format in all places in my app based on user locale settings and noticed that. I was looking for best solution for that but I didn't find any reasonable one for my requirement. Only possible solution I have found requires to construct map with locale codes and formats  (en_US -> 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a')? What do you think about that @glls?

Comment: =)  That itself is a different question, mind opening a new one with the details and current approach?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @glls. I will open new question for that and mark here your answer as best.